# Error during assigning product image through soap api Magento

Tags: magento, soap, error-handling, media, product

HI i have just start learning soap api in magento . In this i have create a product through soap and now i want to assign product images through it.
for that i am using below code

```
<?php $client = new SoapClient('http://localhost/magento1.9/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');


$session = $client->login('111111', '111111');


$newImage = array(
    'file' => array(
        'name' => 'file_name',
        'content' => base64_encode(file_get_contents('heart_circle.png')),
        'mime'    => 'image/jpeg'
    ),
    'label'    => 'Cool Image Through Soap',
    'position' => 2,
    'types'    => array('small_image'),
    'exclude'  => 0
);

$imageFilename = $client->call($session, 'product_media.create', array('product_sku', $newImage));


var_dump($imageFilename);



?>
```

> but i am getting below error Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault
>   exception: [Client] Function ("call") is not a valid method for this
>   service in /var/www/soap.php:19 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/soap.php(19):
>   SoapClient->__call('call', Array) #1 /var/www/soap.php(19):
>   SoapClient->call('92b56ed9ed1c9b5...', 'product_media.c...', Array) #2
>   {main} thrown in /var/www/soap.php on line 19

Please suggest me where i am doing mistake. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have found the issue it was the wrong soap version mention in the url

```
http://localhost/magento1.9/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl  //previous
http://localhost/magento1.9/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl     // new
```

thanks